# Track count of views,likes and comments in a community site

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, looker-studio

Can anyone tell me how can I track number of views,likes,comments and shares in a collaboration and community site. This is not a Google site. This site was created using lumapps. It's a collaboration site, Which works similar to Google+, where you can write a blog, post and like/ share the same. I need a way of keep tracking the likes/shares/views on such posts or blogs, So that I can display the same in Google data studio.

I heard it's possible using Google tag manager. Can anyone confirm this OR let me know about anyways of achieving the same.

Thanks and Regards
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by sending an event to Google Analytics and using this source in Data Studios.

Please see reference on how to send events using Google Tag Manager and custom Variables.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716?hl=en